# Return type of CvMat's type attribute is 1111638021 instead of 5 or 6..pointer error?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having a really strange bug, and maybe it is a pointer error, but I can't see it.  I have the following code...

```
// file scope
static CvMat *cam1_points;
const int n_boards = 2;
const int board_n = 54;

// snip

// function scope...
void initializeAndDoStuff()
{
    cam1_points = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_n, 2, CV_32FC1);
    printf("Type: %d\n", cam1_points->type); // should be 5.  returns crazy number in title.
};
```

Is something going wrong somewhere?  Why am I not getting the right response?  Type should be returning `CV_32F`, which qualifies to the integer 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` is the matrix signature which stores more than the function type. You're getting the "strange" number because it's the result of the following bitwise OR operations.

```
CV_MAT_MAGIC_VAL|5|CV_MAT_CONT_FLAG
```

So, that's how you can use `type` to check if your matrix belongs to a particular type, or is continuous, etc.

Note that if you use the C++ version (`cv::Mat`) then `type` would return `5`.

Comment: Strange.  Because of this, my code is failing in cvStereoCalibrate when checking the type.  It is failing the assert that checks whether a matrix is type CV_32F or CV_64F..

Comment: If you have the source code, you can fix `cvStereoCalibrate` for now, recompile the binaries and submit a bug fix.

Comment: I will look into it.  Spend a bit more time looking at it first, but you're right.  Bitwise oring those things together gives the resultant number.  Thanks again!