# How to determine the data type of a CvMat

Tags: c, opencv

When using the `CvMat` type, the type of data is crucial to keeping your program running.

For example, depending on whether your data is type `float` or `unsigned char`, you would choose one of these two commands:

```
cvmGet(mat, row, col);
cvGetReal2D(mat, row, col);
```

Is there a universal approach to this?  If the wrong data type matrix is passed to these calls, they crash at runtime.  This is becoming an issue, since a function I have defined is getting passed several different types of matrices.

How do you determine the data type of a matrix so you can always access its data?

I tried using the "type()" function as such.

```
CvMat* tmp_ptr = cvCreateMat(t_height,t_width,CV_8U);
std::cout << "type = " << tmp_ptr->type() << std::endl;
```

This does not compile, saying `"term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"`.  If I remove the brackets after the word `type`, I get a type of 1111638032

*EDIT* minimal application that reproduces this...

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CvMat *tmp2 = cvCreateMat(10,10, CV_32FC1);
    std::cout << "tmp2 type = " << tmp2->type << " and CV_32FC1 = " << CV_32FC1 << " and " << (tmp2->type == CV_32FC1) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: `tmp2 type = 1111638021 and CV_32FC1 = 5 and 0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The `type` is a variable, NOT a function**:

```
CvMat* tmp_ptr = cvCreateMat(t_height,t_width,CV_8U);
std::cout << "type = " << tmp_ptr->type << std::endl;
```

**EDIT:**

As for the unusual value of `type` being printed, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707361/176769), this variable stores more than the data type.

So the appropriate way of checking `cvMat` data type is using the macro `CV_MAT_TYPE()`:

```
CvMat *tmp2 = cvCreateMat(3,1, CV_32FC1);
std::cout << "tmp2 type = " << tmp2->type << " and CV_32FC1 = " << CV_32FC1 << " and " << (CV_MAT_TYPE(tmp2->type) == CV_32FC1) << std::endl;
```

The naming convention of the data type is:

```
CV_<bit_depth>(S|U|F)C<number_of_channels>

S = Signed integer
U = Unsigned integer
F = Float 

E.g.: CV_8UC1 means an 8-bit unsigned single-channel matrix, 
      CV_32FC2 means a 32-bit float matrix with two channels.
```

Comment: See, this is what I thought, but the result of type is 1111638032, which is totally wrong.CV_8U should result in the integer 0.  This is where my confusion comes from.  Why would the type be so wrong?

Comment: What if you create the mat with `CV_8UC1`? What is the size of the mat (width/height) you are trying to create? You are not testing the success of `cvCreateMat()`, it might be a good idea.

Comment: Same idea.. I tried again with 32FC1.  CvMat *tmp2 = cvCreateMat(10,10, CV_32FC1);  I compared tmp2->type against CV_32FC1.  tmp2->type gives 1111638021 and the cv float gives 5.

Comment: Please write a complete minimal application and put it in your question so we can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Added the minimal application to the question

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called

```
CV_MAT_TYPE()
```

So you can do something like this

```
CV_MAT_TYPE(tmp2->type)
```

That is going to return the 5 you need which is equivalent to the CV_32FC1.

PO. I came looking for what was the meaning of the 5 I was getting with CV_MAT_TYPE, so you gave me the answer with your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of type() functions to return the  data type, both size and number of channels see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cvmat

Comment: Thanks.  I saw these functions previously, but the 'type' function is not working for me.  If I use mat->type(), this no longer compiles.  "Term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"

Comment: link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

While the issue at hand is related to calling/accessing the 'type' member of the Mat class I believe that the CV_ENUM usage deployed in the ts module of opencv will provide you with a more informative alternative.

The type is essentially built from the 'depth' member value and the 'channels' member value. By using the MatDepth enumeration in the ts-module the method PrintTo is available.

If you wish you can probably extract the channel count from the type simply by masking (&-operator) the bit value and inspecting the remaining bits.

```
#include <opencv2/ts/ts_perf.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Method for printing the information related to an image                                                                                                                                              
void printImageInfo(std::ostream * os, cv::Mat * image){
  int type = image->type();
  int channels = image->channels();
  cv::Size imageSize = image->size();
  perf::MatDepth depth(image->depth());
  *os << "Image information: " << imageSize << " type " << type
      << " channels " << channels << " ";
  *os << "depth " << depth << " (";
  depth.PrintTo(os);
  *os << ")" << std::endl;
```

}